# YEARFRAC function in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

When I create a formula `=YEARFRAC("1/1/2017","12/31/2017")` it returns 1. One year between 1/1/17 & 12/31/17. However when I create `=YEARFRAC("1/1/2017","06/30/2017")` I was expecting 0.5 i.e. six months from 1/1/17 thru 6/30/17, but it returns 0.4972

However when one more day is added to it i.e. `=YEARFRAC("1/1/2017","07/01/2017")` it now returns 0.5.

I am not very clear how this function really works. Which is the most correct option for the [basis] parameter i.e. third optional parameter in YEARFRAC?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty good question, and surprisingly there are not many resources on that.

Office help on [`YEARFRAC()`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/YEARFRAC-function-3844141e-c76d-4143-82b6-208454ddc6a8) gives some information, but not many details on the calculation itself.

The system behind the calculation is called "[Day count convention](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/d/daycount.asp)" and it is used mainly in finance calculating interest rates and payments.

It has slightly different variations, some of them are covered by the parameters of `YEARFRAC()`.

Not having experience with it I can't explain the system for you, however just created a small table showing function's output for beginning and end of each month in a year, it might help you choosing the one best fit your need.

[image]

The formula used for the calculation is
`=ROUND(YEARFRAC($B$3,$B3,D$2),3)`

Answer (score 1):

You are mistaken with the output of the function. Here is the description for the function :

> Calculates the fraction of the year represented by the number of whole days **between** two dates (the start_date and the end_date). Use the **YEARFRAC** worksheet function to identify the proportion of a whole year's benefits or obligations to assign to a specific term.

Can you observe the line that says : *number of whole days between two dates (the start_date and the end_date)* , i.e. when you are using 30/06/2017 , you are not considering that date for inclusion which leads to different value than expected.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide a third argument to the function, Excel used the default setting of 30/360 US Convention.

There is very little documentation on the specific details of how YEARFRAC in Excel works for 30/360 if it's the 31st day of the month. I tracked down an obscure specification below.

> If the dates are equal, the difference of days is 0. Assumes that each
> month has 30 days and the total number of days in the year is 360 by
> making the following adjustments:
>
> 1. If both day-of-months are 31, they are changed to 30
> 2. Otherwise, if date1’s day-of-month is 31, it is changed to 30
> 3. Otherwise, if date1’s day-of-month is 30 and date2’s day-of-month is 31, date2’s day-of-month is changed to 30 (note that date2’s
>    day-of-month will stay 31 if date1’s day < 30)
> 4. Otherwise, if both dates are the last day of February in their respective years, both day-of-month is changed to 30
> 5. Otherwise, if date1 is the last day of February, its day-of-month is changed to 30

So in your example, `=YEARFRAC("1/1/2017","06/30/2017")` is only counting 179 days because it counts the first half of the year exclusive. Similar to counting the days between January 1st and January 2nd is only 1 day even though the time period includes two days.

The `=YEARFRAC("1/1/2017","12/31/2017")` is what is less intuitive. Because date1 is the 1st of the month and date2 is the 31st, Excel still treats date 2 like the 31st even though 30/360 should mean that every month has 30 days. An interesting result of this is that `=YEARFRAC("12/31/2016","12/31/2017")` also gives you a result of 1.